# About unit-test dependency

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'm trying to code some basic unit-tests for a project I am currently working on where I have my service that has a method `addPlaneModel` to add a plane model (under the hood it adds a `PlaneModel` instance into a `TreeMap` and throws a custom exception if the `TreeMap` already contains the key).

I could write a test (for example `shouldAddNewPlane_Succeed`) to see if it's properly adding the `PlaneModel` but my problem comes if I wanted to create a test to see if the `PlaneModel` already existed (for example `shouldAddNewPlane_ThrowExistingModelException` because I should call `addPlaneModel` twice to make it throw the exception, but if `shouldAddNewPlane_Succeed` test doesn't run first, I don't really 'know' if that method works as it should.

I've read that unit-tests should be independant from each other but I can't really grasp how to do it in this case, do I necessarily have to run them in order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be creating a new instance of the class you are testing before each test.

So your test class will look like:

```java
class MyTests {
  private MyService myService;

  @Before // junit 4, or @BeforeEach for junit 5
  public void setup() {
    myService = new MyService(... pass mocks of dependencies ...);
  }

  @Test
  public void aTest() {
    myService...
  }

  @Test
  public void aTest2() {
    myService... // this is a fresh instance of MyService, any changes to the
                 // state of the instance used in aTest() are gone.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute some common code before running a test, you can use the `@Before` method annotation in JUnit. For instance:

```
@Before
public void init() {
    LOG.info("startup");
    list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("test1", "test2"));
}
```

This code will always execute before any other test that you run. This is useful to define a certain order for execution to your tests.